# Animation when changing child widget by index

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in Flutter, and so I have a list of widgets,

```
final List<Widget> _backgrounds = [
 const BackgroundDesign(index: 0),
 const BackgroundDesign(index: 1),
 const BackgroundDesign(index: 2),
 const BackgroundDesign(index: 3)
];
```

this code and navigator:

```
IndexedStack(children: [
 Center(
  child: _backgrounds.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
 )
],),
```

It changes `_selectedIndex` on click, so the result looks like this:
[image: box1]
[image: box2]

So what i am trying to achieve is `_backgrounds.elementAt(_selectedIndex)` to be changed with fade animation. Is there any solution for this? Thank you.

Comment: IndexedStack is preloaded pages in order to switch quickly between pages. So use navigation instead. There is TransionBuilder that you can add any transition you want.